# Passing argument pairs with varargs without running into bad patterns

Tags: java

Originally we had an object, which was constructed as follows:

```
FieldSet set = new FieldsSet(
    new Field("stringField", "aaa"),
    new Field("booleanField", Boolean.FALSE),
    new Field("intValue", new Integer(123));
```

but it was seems tedious to construct Field object each time (in this example I gave 3 fields, but usually it's more like 20). So we added the following method:

```
public static FieldSet getNewInstance(Object... fieldPairs) {

    ArrayList<Field> fields = new ArrayList<Field>();

    for (int i = 0; i < fieldPairs.length; i += 2) {
        fields.add(new Field(fieldPairs[i].toString(), fieldPairs[i + 1]));
    }

    return new FieldSet(fields.toArray(new Field[fields.size()]));
}
```

which we can use like this:

```
FieldSet set = FieldSet.getNewInstance(
        "stringField", "aaa", 
        "booleanField", Boolean.FALSE, 
        "intValue", new Integer(123));
```

As you see it carries a bad pattern of using argument placement to convey 2 types of arguments.

So I am trying to find a better pattern that

- Allows the user to construct `FieldSet`, in a fairly concise form, i.e. avoids the need to tediously create `Field` object many times
- Avoids bad patterns, such as the one above

Below are relevant portions of FieldSet and Field:

```
public class FieldSet { 
    ArrayList<Field> fields = new ArrayList<Field>();

    public FieldSet(Field... fields) {
        for(Field field : fields) {
            this.fields.add(field);
        }
    }
}

public class Field {
    private String name;
    private Object value;

    public Field(String name, Object value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Note: the code I provided here was created specifically to demonstrate the question in simplest form, so please don't pay attention at some other inefficiencies (e.g. converting back and forth between array and `ArrayList` - that problem is not part of the real code)

Thanks!

Comment: It would be so nice if someone would invent something like a builder pattern which has a method `addField` which accepts two arguments, so one could use it to build a `FieldSet` instance in a quite clean way. It would be so nice.

Comment: @Tom this is a good suggestion indeed, why wouldn't post it as an answer?

Comment: @AndreyMormysh Because he felt the disturbance in the force of me already doing so. ;-)

Comment: @Andreas haha :) I see.. Also it feels Java becomes less convenient in these cases when you need to take care of multiple types and have objects (FieldSet) whch can not be described as a class but rather just a bunch of data.

Comment: @AndreyMormysh I rarely write answers nowadays, but mostly a comment to push OP into the right direction. When the question itself is interessting or not obvious, then I might answer it :).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The original way is the right way. Any other way will lose compiler type-checking, or be more cumbersome to use.

Though a [builder](http://www.oodesign.com/builder-pattern.html) might be an option:

```
FieldSet set = FieldSet.builder()
        .add("stringField", "aaa")
        .add("booleanField", Boolean.FALSE)
        .add("intValue", new Integer(123))
        .build();
```